# Parse XML input from UDP port

Tags: python, xml, sockets, udp

I'm a newbie in python, just done only a couple of scripts.

Now I need to listen and process a xml text that is being received from a udp socket.

By the moment I have the first part but i don't know how to proceed.

```
import socket
import lxml.etree


port = 7059
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", port))
print "waiting on port:", port
while 1:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print data
```

I'm receiving the data ok, and it's printed on the screen:

```
<electricity id='4437190066CD'><timestamp>1532728995</timestamp><signal rssi='-78' lqi='94'/><battery level='10%'/><chan id='0'><curr units='w'>609.00</curr><day units='wh'>34.64</day></chan><chan id='1'><curr units='w'>42.00</curr><day units='wh'>2.38</day></chan><chan id='2'><curr units='w'>538.00</curr><day units='wh'>30.43</day></chan></electricity>
```

But I need to get or parse de values in bold:

```
<chan id='0'><curr units='w'>609.00</curr>
<chan id='1'><curr units='w'>42.00</curr>
<chan id='2'><curr units='w'>538.00</curr>
```

and asign to something like a var with it's sub objects:

power.ch0 = 609.00

power.ch1 = 42.00

power.ch2 = 538.00

with that variable, then I will do a request to my porwer monitoring system api to send these values.

I usually use bash for scripting, and I'm pretty happy with it, but I think that this time not rich enough and python seems to be my solution

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  First, I do not see where you are using the xml.etree module.  Take a look at the docs real fast: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Also, you can achieve this with BeautifulSoup as well: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Lastly, you can achieve this with the .replace() and .strip() functions as well